# HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL even with no doget() method

Tags: java

I'm trying to link the register information to database mysql. Everything work fine when i exported the data to the text file but when trying to connect with database, it always get this error. Here is my code I have try so far:
Register.jsp:

```
enter code here
<form action="./Data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> Username </td>
            <td><input type ="text" name="uname" size="30"required></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Your email address </td>
            <td><input type ="text" name="mail" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="pass" size="20"required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Please re-type your password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="p2" size="20"required></td>
        </tr>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Date of Birth</td>
            <td><select name="Type">
                    <%for(int i=1;i<=31;i++) {%>
                    <option><%=i%></option>
                    <%}%>  
                </select></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="Type">
                        <option>January</option>
                        <option>February</option>
                        <option>March</option>
                        <option>April</option>
                        <option>May</option>
                        <option>June</option>
                        <option>July</option>
                        <option>August</option>
                        <option>September</option>
                        <option>October</option>
                        <option>November</option>
                        <option>December</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="Type">
                       <% for (int j=1970;j<=2010;j++) {%>
                       <option><%=j%></option>
                       <%}%>
                    </select>

                </td>


        <tr>
            <td>Gender</td>
            <td><input type ="radio" value="r1" checked name="Gender">Male</td>
            <td><input type ="radio" value="r2" checked name="Gender">Female</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Register" name="s4"></td>
            <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" name="s5"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>

enter code here
```

Data.java:

```
enter code here
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/Data"})
public class Data extends HttpServlet {


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            String user = request.getParameter("uname");
            String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
            String email = request.getParameter("mail");
            String gender = request.getParameter("Gender");
            String end = ("----------------------");


        Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver").newInstance();
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8084/userinfo";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL,"root","");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;  
        int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into userinfo (Username, email, password) values('" + user + "','" + pass + "','" + email + "')");
         if (i > 0) {

        response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
        out.print("Registration Successfull!"+"<a href='index.jsp'>Go to Login</a>");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
        response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");

        }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Data` class extends `HttpServlet` which implements the `doGet()` method.

When the `Servlet` container receives any request, it will call your `Servlet'`s `service()` method. In this case, that is the inherited `HttpServlet#service()` method which calls the `HttpServlet#doGet()` method. Since you haven't implemented that method, your class inherits it. In the `HttpServlet` class, it is implemented like so

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String protocol = req.getProtocol();
    String msg = lStrings.getString("http.method_get_not_supported");
    if (protocol.endsWith("1.1")) {
        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, msg);
    } else {
        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, msg);
    }
}
```

Therefore, when you send a GET request, this method will be invoked and you will get the 405 response code.

Implement your own `doGet()` which delegates to `processRequest`.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
    processRequest(req, resp);
}
```